# If $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then $a + b = c$?

Tags: functions

I know this question is really dumb to ask and it's not true at all, but I wanna know why...

If $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then if we take the square root of both sides, it results with a + b = c... However, if we just directly took a, b, c without squaring then dividing, the value of c is different as opposed to if we did (like Pythagoras theorem)

Comment: Notice that $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$. Therefore, by letting $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ for integers $a, b, c$, if we square root, we have that $c = \sqrt {(a + b)^2 - 2ab}$. If $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = a + b$, then $c = a + b - \sqrt{2ab}$, but $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be expressed as a fraction and thus $c$ is irrational, which is a contradiction  since $c$ is an integer. This is why $\sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \neq a + b$.

Comment: This further implies that $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ since when you square root both sides, they apparently equal each other. But we just expressed $(a + b)^2$ as $a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$, therefore $2ab = 0$ for all integers $a$ and $b$. Since this is absurd, it follows then that there exists no solutions for integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, but there are infinitely many counter-examples, so the mathematics is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

Take $a=3, b=4, c=5$.

$a^2+b^2=c^2$, since $9+16=25$ but $a+b\neq c$, since $3+4\neq 5$.

The reason is that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\neq \sqrt{a^2}+\sqrt{b^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $a+b=c$ and squared both parts $a^2+2ab+b^2=c^2$. For $a^2+b^2=c^2$ it should be $2ab=0$. That's why $a^2+b^2=c^2$ only when $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of geometry:

Let $a,b$, and $c$ be the sides of a right triangle, $c$ the hypotenuse :

Pythagoras:

$a^2+b^2=c^2.$

Example : $3,4$, hypotenuse $5$:

$3^2+4^2 =5^2.$

In any triangle:

$a +b > c$ , I.e.

the sum of $2$ sides is greater than the third side.

The answer to your question is?